# Maximizing overlap of high-low set

Tags: algorithm, optimization, approximation, mixed-integer-programming, np-hard

I have a finite sequence of random positive integer numbers a1,…,aM  and I am looking for an *approximation algorithm* (not exact) that finds  sequence of  z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6 (**zigzag**) that starts with z1=a1 in order to maximize overlap of High-Low signal, set H=[z3-z2,z5-z4] and set L=[z4-z1,z6-z3] (one of the set is less than zero and another one is greater than zero) .
How do I approach this optimization problem? Ideally, I am looking for an efficient algorithm that can find the optimal sequence (zi) given any input sequence (ai), typically containing millions of elements.

Comment: How a set can be "less than zero"? Can you explain the problem better, perhaps with an example or two?

Comment: Ok... A sequence of integers is called zigzag sequence if each of its elements is either strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors.

Example : The sequence 4 2 3 1 5 3 forms a zigzag, but 7 3 5 5 2 and 3 8 6 4 5 don't.
set L contains elements that they are less than zero..and set H contains elements that they are greater than zero

Comment: In two of your three examples, the sequence contains five points, but in your definition, you need six points. Moreover, in your first example, z_6 - z_3 = 0, which doesn't seem to be allowed according to your explanation, yet you state that the sequence is a zigzag. And other than z_1 = a_1, what is the relation between a_i and z_i; is the latter a subsequence of the former, or something like that? And where does the optimization come in; what's your objective?

Comment: Examples clear the definition of a zigzag,then five point are typicaly for definition a zigzag and they arent elements of real a_i I think i have to further explain the problem, a_i has one million elements, i'm interested to find six elements of a_i that have to be zigzag pattern(according to definition of zigzag).these six elements of a_i must have some properties: 
1) H=[z3-z2,z5-z4] subject to, z3-z2>0,z5-z4>0 (as definition of zigzag)
 2) L=[z4-z1,z6-z3], subject to z4-z1<0,z6-z3<0...
plot(H_L=[H;L] ) has 2 hi_low elements that have an overlap,i'm interested to maximize this overlap